# Restoring SIMD registers on Windows x64 during unwinding

Tags: windows, 64-bit, stack-unwinding, structured-exception

On Windows x86-64, how are callee-saved SIMD registers restored during unwinding?  If one was writing assembly code, how would one ensure that this happened properly?

Comment: x64 stack unwinding is rocket science, certainly best left to a compiler.  It requires metadata, [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2010/05/12/x64-manual-stack-reconstruction-and-stack-walking/) talks about it.  Many more web pages like that, little point in repeating it here.

Comment: @HansPassant what if I am writing assembly code by hand (ex. numerics kernel, crypto kernel (not that I would roll-my-own crypto for production), interpreter main loop, etc?)  Or what if I am JIT-compiling?

Comment: Then you'd better figure out what the metadata needs to look like.  It is not a secret, merely convoluted.

Comment: This is NOT too broad because anyone writing x86-64 SIMD assembler needs to know this if one is to be able to handle exceptions thrown when a callee-save SIMD register has been temporarily modified.

Comment: @HansPassant I am asking what the instruction stream would be.

Comment: From the blog entry posted by Hans Passant: *"If you happen to code in assembly language, there are various macros that you must use to decorate your assembly code so that the assembler can generate the proper unwind metadata."* So either you let the assembler construct the metadata for you, or you need to build the tables yourself, by hand.

Comment: @IInspectable I found those macros, but would like to know what they expand to so I could use a different assembler such as YASM or GAS.

Comment: @Demetri: The [Unwind Helpers for MASM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235241.aspx) do not expand to anything. They are understood by the assembler (MASM in this case), and it uses them to construct the tables with metadata that are linked into the final binary image. If you want to use another assembler you'll have to use the facilities those assemblers provide to generate the unwind metadata.